# What is the atmospheric pressure inside upside down cup?

Tags: fluid-statics

If we turn a cup upside down, what is the value of atmospheric pressure inside it and why?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Same as it would be if the cup were aimed upwards. This may be confusing as the upper air responsible for the pressure in an "upright cup" is not directly pressing down on the "upside down" cup air, but, it is still pressing down on the air around the bottom (open end) of the "upside down" cup. As a result, even if turning the cup around did lower the air—pressure inside of it, due to diffusion, the higher pressure air surrounding the cup would quickly push into the low pressure system, until the air—pressure inside the cup is at equilibrium with it's surroundings— equal pressure at equal depths in fluids.